# BeginTransaction(string) in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I want to use a database transaction with the name( a string) in EF 6.

I found a`BeginTransaction()`  method, but it only has a `IsolationLevel` Parameter: `BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel)`
Is there a way to use a transaction with a string in EF6?

Comment: I think the new transaction paradigm in ADO.NET doesn't use naming of transactions but instead uses ambient transactions via TransactionScope. Any reason why you would want to name the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit elaborate, but you can use an existing connection + transaction in a `DbContext`. I adapted the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843#existing) to create a named transaction:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var trn = conn.BeginTransaction("TransactionName"))
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext(conn, false))
        {
            db.Database.UseTransaction(trn);
            ... // your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your context class should implement [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and that the second parameter (`contextOwnsConnection`) must be `false`. Or use a constructor that defaults to false:

```
public MyContext(DbConnection connection)
    : base(connection, false)
{ }
```